# 3D rotation group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, rotations

It is known that the group $\text{SO}(3)$ of rotation-matrices (matrices $A$ with $\det(A)=1$)
are generated from three parameters. This can be expressed by the fact, that
any rotation matrix is a composition of axis rotations

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\phi)&-\sin(\phi)&0\\
\sin(\phi)&\cos(\phi)&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\phi)&0&\sin(\phi)\\
0&1&0\\
-\sin(\phi)&0&\cos(\phi)\\
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&\cos(\phi)&-\sin(\phi)\\
0&\sin(\phi)&\cos(\phi)\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The question is: Why is the second matrix (Usually called rotation around the $y$-axis ) in almost any textbook written like this?

Related to the other two matrices, I would say that the negative 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\phi)&0&-\sin(\phi)\\
0&1&0\\
\sin(\phi)&0&\cos(\phi)\\
\end{pmatrix},
$$
is conceptual more straight forward. Any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: This way all three matrices can be transformed into each other by cyclic shifts of coordinates.

Comment: That makes it more natural in my opinion.

Comment: a) This is not its negative; it's the transpose and the inverse. b) The question is hard to answer without you stating why you think this would be conceptually more straightforward.

Comment: Yes I was wrong about the negative.

Comment: In the second style you can define the fundamental vector fields of the action on $\mathbb{R}^3$ as $M_{ij}:=x_i\partial_j -x_j\partial_i$ for $i<j$, but you have to write the second field wit a different sign if you use the former version.

Comment: Moreover this twist is present in the vector product, too. And you see it frequently in $2$-forms on $\mathbb{R}^3$. (Mostly in the area of stokes formular) Anyway this is maybe just a historical accident.

Comment: @George Please don't add "thanks in advance" and its variants to posts by other users. Such pleasantries are often considered noise on the SE network (see [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950) and [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97136)). While minimal amounts of pleasantries coming directly from posters are deemed fine here on Math, editing them in is not improving posts but rather shoving words in people's mouths.

Answer (score 3):

Note that all the matrices listed will rotate vectors by the angle $\phi$ around the $x,y$ and $z$ axis respectively. The alternating signs is a result of the right hand screw rule. Let 
\begin{equation*}
A=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
\cos(\phi) & 0 & \sin(\phi) \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
-\sin(\phi) & 0 & \cos(\theta)
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr).
\end{equation*}

Note that to be a rotation matrix, we must have $A^T=A^{-1}$ and $\det A=1$ which you can check holds by an elementary computation. The locations of all the elements in the $y-$axis rotation matrix are placed so that we have a rotation around the $y-$axis. For example, suppose we are in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and we want to rotate the vector $(0,0,1)$ (aligned with the $z-$axis) $90^o$s. Then multiplying $A$ evaluated at $\phi=90$ by this unit vector gives $(1,0,0)$ which geometrically is a $90^o$ anticlockwise direction around the $y-$axis.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not going to be even remotely rigorous, but to get a better geometric mnemonic of the sign-flip’s purpose:

Consider that the ordering of the x,y,z axes is cyclical: cyclical ordering implies that only *cyclical* permutation has certain kinds of meaning. The expression that gives us the number of cyclical permutations is (n-1)!. In other words, there are *precisely* 2 self-cyclically-isomorphic orderings of ℝ^3 base vectors, and they happen to be the reverse of each-other. Transitioning between one cyclical permutation and the other is geometrically isomorphic to a chirality-switching sign-flip in an ℝ^3 set of basis vectors.

In other words, there are *precisely* 2 cyclical permutations of a matrix’s columns (or rows). Each of the two cyclical permutations contains all three *linear* permutations that have the same sign/chirality (visualize cycling from one to another by exchanging every base cyclically: no such transform requires a mirror-flip).

The (thoroughly non-rigorous, incorrect-if-generalized) mnemonic arises when you consider that the y-axis rotation matrix “skips over” the center row & column. Consider this non-adjacent-elements 3-choose-2 operation as a kind of “sign-flipped” version of the two other *adjacent-elements* 3-choose-2 operations, belonging to the *other*, sign-flipped cyclical permutation. Alternatively, consider the “cycling back around” 3-choose-2 operation to be sign-flipping.

The whole “precisely two cyclical permutations, precisely two chiralities” analogy breaks down in higher dimensions, but every (linear?) permutation still has an associated chirality sign (probably applicable in a *correct* generalization, and equivalent to the sign-obtaining function used in finding a determinant). Also, higher dimensions have entire separate classes of rotation, and I don’t know a lot about it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).